# H2o.ensemble: family <- "gaussian", error with family = gamma requires a positive response

Tags: r, gaussian, h2o, ensemble-learning

Error in h2o.ensemble(x = x, y = y, training_frame = train, family = family, : family = gamma requires a positive respone
Traceback:

1. h2o.ensemble(x = x, y = y, training_frame = train, family = family, 
   .     learner = learner, metalearner = metalearner, cvControl = list(V = 5, 
   .         shuffle = TRUE))
2. stop("family = gamma requires a positive respone")

reponse "y" is with both negative and positive values.`

**code**:

```
## Load required packages
library(h2o)
library(h2oEnsemble)

h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = "8G")

data <- h2o.importFile('./input/df_train.csv')

# Partition the data into train and test sets
splits <- h2o.splitFrame(data, seed = 1)
train <- splits[[1]]
test <- splits[[2]]

# Identify response and predictor variables
y <- "logerror"
x <- setdiff(colnames(data), c(y, "parcelid", "transactiondate"))
print(x)


# Specify the base learner library & the metalearner
learner <- c("h2o.glm.wrapper", "h2o.randomForest.wrapper", 
            "h2o.xgboost.wrapper",
            "h2o.gbm.wrapper", "h2o.deeplearning.wrapper")
metalearner <- "h2o.glm.wrapper"
family <- "gaussian"

# Train the ensemble using 5-fold CV to generate level-one data

fit <- h2o.ensemble(x = x, y = y,
                training_frame = train,
                family = family,
                learner = learner,
                metalearner = metalearner,
                cvControl = list(V = 5, shuffle = TRUE))

# Evaluate performance on a test set
perf <- h2o.ensemble_performance(fit, newdata = test)
perf
```

Comment: please post a fully reproducible code snippet, the version of h2o you are using and include your error message.

Comment: h2oEnsemble R package for H2O-3
Version: 0.2.0 , H2O cluster version:  3.10.5.3

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in **h2oEnsemble** v0.2.0 that was introduced when I added support for the extra `family` values (gamma, poisson, etc).  I have [fixed the bug](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/1427/commits/0043585a43d8ce730c12c07f7e8cbc52257ff820) and released a **h2oEnsemble** v0.2.1; you can find a link to download the new package [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/master/h2o-r/ensemble#installation), or use the R command below:

```
install.packages("https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-ensemble/R/h2oEnsemble_0.2.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
```

On a separate note, your code attempts to include an XGBoost model by using a wrapper, `"h2o.xgboost.wrapper"` -- there is no built-in wrapper for XGBoost in the **h2oEnsemble** package yet, so that won't work.  I will add the XGBoost wrapper after **h2o** 3.14.0.1 is released.  That should happen in the next week or two.